# setting micronaut configuration location

Tags: groovy, micronaut

I have an existing groovy micronaut app I'm trying to change where it loads its config from. I don't understand what code to write so I can set the location of the micronaut configuration. I know you can use micronaut.config.files system variable or MICRONAUT_CONFIG_FILES environment variable, but this is a terrible idea because micronaut is built into grails and therefore every grails app you have running in tomcat will pick up the same config and crash.

Nor do I know where in the code to set the config file. There's an Application class with a run() method, but I don't know if this is only called during development, or whether it gets called when deploying in Tomcat. When setting the config in a Grails app, there is an Application class extending EnvironmentAware, and you can override setEnvironment, and load external configs there, but there is no hint of that for micronaut apps.

The micronaut doco says it can load a configuration from "application.{extension}", but it doesn't say what "application" is, or what directory it expects that in, or whether you can change the directory. Is "application" the value of micronaut.application.name in one's application.yml? I couldn't seem to get it to load based on that.

Then the documentation talks about loading from a PropertySource, which is fine and all, but doesn't tell you where you can put that code to load from a PropertySource. There is mention you can pass the PropertySource to ApplicationContext.run(xx), but in this app I inherited, there is no mention of ApplicationContext, and the micronaut documentation isn't very clear what I'm supposed to do with ApplicationContext. This app I've inherited has an Application class with a main() calling Micronaut.run() which apparently returns an ApplicationContext, but it's not clear if main() is called when running in Tomcat, or whether I should be calling run() on that, when it works as is, and I'm just trying to change where it loads its config.

Comment: "The micronaut doco says it can load a configuration from "application.{extension}", but it doesn't say what "application" is" - "application" is literally "application".  The file name could be `src/main/resources/application.yml`, `src/main/resources/application.json`, `src/main/resources/application.properties` etc. .

Comment: " but this is a terrible idea because micronaut is built into grails and therefore every grails app you have running in tomcat will pick up the same config and crash" - I don't believe that is true if the environments are configured correctly.  You can env variables per app.  If you are interested in solving that problem in a Grails app, please post a separate question.  That can be easily addressed.  Best of luck!

Comment: Is the question you are asking something like "what are all of the ways I can specify external config files"?

Comment: "There's an Application class with a run() method, but I don't know if this is only called during development, or whether it gets called when deploying in Tomcat." - It is not only called during development but it is not called when deploying to Tomcat.  Under normal circumstances that method is only used when running the executable jar or running in your dev env, which you not be doing if you were deploying to a Tomcat instance.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown since it is the micronaut embedded WITHIN grails that picks up micronaut.config.files system variable, and since I don't have the power to go and edit the source code of every grails app deployed in Tomcat, it seems to me that this is a micronaut question, not a grails question. The question is, how do I get my micronaut app to load its config from where I tell it to, and not from micronaut.config.file system variable location.

Comment: To my knowledge you can't have per-app Environment variables (in the sense of System.getEnv()) in Tomcat. There is a context.getEnvironment() variable, but that's not the same thing, micronaut uses OS environment variables, not tomact environment variables which are setup in xml config

Comment: I suspected that application.groovy was a literal, so that doesn't help with per-app configuration. And I suspected that main() isn't called, so again, I don't know where to put code to set the config file, and I don't know what that code would be.

Comment: " it seems to me that this is a micronaut question, not a grails question" - Understood.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

> The question is, how do I get my micronaut app to load its config from
> where I tell it to, and not from micronaut.config.file system variable
> location.

I don't think we have a specific feature in the framework that allows you to tell the framework to ignore `micronaut.config.files`.  If you would like such a feature you can request it at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues.  If that is of interest I suggest you open it up for discussion at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/discussions first.

Comment: I don't need it to ignore micronaut.config.files ...., I can just not set that variable. I just need another way to tell it where I DO want it to take its config from.

Comment: "I don't need it to ignore micronaut.config.files" - The question says "and not from micronaut.config.file system variable location".

Comment: @xpusostomos This won't address "and not from micronaut.config.file system variable location" which is why it isn't in the answer but if I were you I would leave all of that out of it and would use a custom `PropertySourceLoader` in your app that can use whatever config variable name you like.  I believe that is a better idea than making the system not use `micronaut.config.files` but again to answer your question, I don't think we provide a feature specifically as a way to have the system not respect `micronaut.config.files`.

Comment: it's not clear how to use it "in your app", when the app is run in Tomcat. Where to put this code?

Comment: "Where to put this code?"  - I would put the source in something like `src/main/java/com/yourpackage/MyCustomPropertySourceLoader.java`.

Answer (score -1):

You can load external config files, from a path not set as `micronaut.config.files`, in the `main` method of the `Application` class before running the application. Take a look at below class which accepts a config folder location as a system property `demo.config.path`(can be something else) and loads yaml config files from that folder:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySource;
import io.micronaut.context.env.yaml.YamlPropertySourceLoader;
import io.micronaut.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import io.micronaut.core.io.file.DefaultFileSystemResourceLoader;
import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut;

public class Application {
    private static final String PROP_CONFIG_LOCATION = "demo.config.path";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (System.getProperty(PROP_CONFIG_LOCATION) != null) {
            List<PropertySource> propertySources = new ArrayList<>();
            YamlPropertySourceLoader propertySourceLoader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
            ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultFileSystemResourceLoader();

            Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(System.getProperty(PROP_CONFIG_LOCATION))).forEach(file -> {
                String fileName = file.toString();
                String fileNameWithoutExtension = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
                propertySourceLoader.load(fileNameWithoutExtension, resourceLoader).ifPresent(propertySources::add);
            });

            Micronaut.build(args)
                    .classes(Application.class)
                    .propertySources(propertySources.toArray(new PropertySource[1]))
                    .start();
        } else {
            Micronaut.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    }
}
```

As is, this code works for `yaml` config files(with `snakeyaml` in classpath). With minor changes, it can be made to work for properties files and to read config location from environment variable instead of system property. Full sample application present in [github](https://github.com/devatherock/micronaut-demo/tree/externalized-config)

Comment: The problem I have with this code is that it is my understanding that main() does not get called when running a Micronaut app in Tomcat. The existing app that I ahve inherited, only has Micronaut.run() in its Applicaiton.main(), which I presume is only there for debugging purposes and isn't called when deploying in Tomcat. This whole problem arises because of its Tomcat deployment.